# Pagination first and second link go to the same page

Tags: javascript, pagination

I am trying to do a pagination starting from current page, so from 1 to 6 for example. At the moment all works fine except for the fact that link 1 and 2 are going to the same page if I turn back to them. If i do 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 it's all good but when I go from 6 to 1 it takes me to link 2 instead of link 1 again. If I look in the console both link 1 and 2 go to page 1. Not sure why, as I am starting with the current link then the link is adding 1. Can you please help. Code below:

```
var current_link = 1;
var navigation_html = '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page('+ current_link +')">' + current_link + '</a>';

while(number_of_pages > current_link){
    navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page('+ current_link +')">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a>';
    current_link++;
}

$('.pagination').html(navigation_html);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you forgot to add the +1 to the function in the while loop.

Change your code to be:

```
var current_link = 1;
var navigation_html = '';

while(number_of_pages >= current_link){
    navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page('+ current_link +')">'+ current_link +'</a>';
    current_link++;
}
```

Comment: That's why I have current_link ++;

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated my question. Basically it does work the first time i go through the links but once I go back to link 1 and 2 they go to page 1 instead of going to 1. Please see my question updated.

Comment: Avitus, I changed the current link to 0 and it works perfect now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(number_of_pages > current_link){
current_link++;
navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page('+ current_link +')">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a>';
}
```

You may want to increment first?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are right, you forgot +1. If not, the first two links shows the same href.

Or use this instead with using a second variable. So current_link always refer to the current page.

```
var current_link = 1, i = current_link +1;
var navigation_html = '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page('+ current_link +')">' + current_link + '</a>';
while(number_of_pages >= i){
    navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page('+ i +')">'+ i +'</a>';
    i++;
}
```